# How to use an Ajax returned object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following code that is used to show some data with the values selected by each of my dropdowns:

```
$("#botao-filtrar").click(function(){
$(".mask-loading").fadeToggle(1000);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php',
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {rede: $("#dropdown-parceria").val(), codLoja: $("#dropdown-loja").val(), mes: $("#dropdown-mes").val()},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Then, at `filtraDashboardGeral.php`, I have the following code that uses the POST variables to filter inside my db and returns an array:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('../../includes/gestaoOriginacao.php');

    $rede = $_POST['rede'];
    $codLoja = $_POST['codLoja'];
    $mes = $_POST['mes'];

    $dados = array();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM evolucao_originacao WHERE redeTratada = '{$rede}' and codLoja = '{$codLoja}' and mesReferencia = '{$mes}'");

    while($valores = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        array_push($dados, $valores);
    }

    echo json_encode($dados);
```

And as you can see, I'm returning the `$dados` in my console. It returns an object:
[image]

I want to use this array object inside my html code. I already tryed something like this inside `success`, but no results:

```
$('span').append(data[0][codLoja]);
```

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Try making `$dados` an `stdClass` instead of array. Then `json_encode` it.

Comment: Try `$.each()` to read all data

Comment: @Jaber I dont know if it will work because each elemento of the array has a different place to be

Comment: @jvbarsou yes, of course you can do that. And then dynamically define properties for this object like so: `$dados-><property_name>`. And also keep in mind PHP's variable of variables, e.g. you can define property name to be anything really: `$a = 'foo'; $dados->$a = <value>;` is equivalent to `$dados->foo = <value>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing quotes: `$('span').append(data[0]["codLoja"])`.

Comment: Thank you @wscourge. I do not know how i did not see that hahaha

Comment: That happens a lot, believe me :)